# Json count elements depending on value of another using Python

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON object that looks like this:

```
[{'key1': 'yes', 'key2': 'yes', 'key3': 'yes'},
 {'key1': 'yes', 'key2': 'no', 'key3': 'yes'},
 {'key1': 'yes', 'key2': 'null', 'key3': 'yes'}]
```

I am trying to count the occurrences of Key1 when the value of Key2 is not yes and I can use that to rank Key1 by the appearance of the value yes in Key2.

Comment: Hi @alecxe I edited the question slightly. I must be really low on Caffeine. What I intend to do is find us my initial count of Key1 which I have as Yes : 409, No: 334, N/A:40 etc and rank its values depending on the appearance of yes in Key2. So my output i something like Yes:60%, No:30%, N/A: 30%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have another answer, it's implemented by 'filter' and 'len':

```
l = [
    {"key1": "yes", "key2": "yes", "key3": "yes"}, 
    {"key1": "yes", "key2": "no", "key3": "yes"}, 
    {"key1": "yes", "key2": "null", "key3": "yes"}
]

f = filter(lambda x: x['key2']!='yes', l)
print f
print len(f)
```

The `print f` outputs the filter result. The `print len(f)` is to further output  the number of the filter result.

```
[{'key3': 'yes', 'key2': 'no', 'key1': 'yes'}, {'key3': 'yes', 'key2': 'null', 'key1': 'yes'}]
2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum):

```
>>> l = [
    {"key1": "yes", "key2": "yes", "key3": "yes"}, 
    {"key1": "yes", "key2": "no", "key3": "yes"}, 
    {"key1": "yes", "key2": "null", "key3": "yes"}
]
>>> sum(item["key2"] != "yes" for item in l)
2
```